# How to use %10 parameter in batch file when all 10 parameters need to be executed at same time?

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file to execute 10 commands at one time as follows but everytime I run it in command prompt. It leaves the last parameter as it is i.e., it ignores the 10th parameter

> echo off 
>      c: 
>      "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1"
>   |   "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%2"
>   |   "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%3"
>   |   "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%4"
>   |   "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%5"
>  |   "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%6"
>   | "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%7"
>   | "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%8"
>   | "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%9"
>   |  SHIFT 
>   |  "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%9"

Any suggestions??

Thanks
Priyanka

Comment: You need to spend time formatting your posts correctly, and using appropriate tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this in a `for` loop:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do (
    "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1"
    SHIFT
)
```

**EDIT:** `shift` doesn't work in a `for` loop because all the lines within the parens are interpreted at the same time, for all iterations, but you can roll your own loop:

```
@echo off
set i=1
:loop
if %i% GEQ 11 goto :end
"H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1"
SHIFT
set /a i+=1
goto :loop

:end
@echo All done.
```

Another solution would be to use a `for` loop but call a sub-procedure to do the `shift`.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for the reply but the above code of loop is not letting me exceute the files simultaneously. I got to use "|" symbol for parallel execution.

Comment: We can do the above as follows echo off  set t1=%1  set t2=%2  set t3=%3  set t4=%4  set t5=%5  set t6=%6  set t7=%7  set t8=%8  set t9=%9  SHIFT  set t10=%9  %t1% | %t2% | %t3% | %t4% | %t5% | %t6% | %t7% | %t8% | %t9% | %t10% @echo all done Thanks all for your comments. I'll be glad if someone can convert the above code in a loop in such a way that any number of inputs can get executed. Regards, Priyanka

Comment: That's an easier problem.  Just replace the `if %i% GEQ 11 goto end` with `if "%1" == "" goto end` and it will handle any number of args.  You can then remove the other two references to i.

Answer (score 1):

You must note that the pipeline character in `PROC1 | PROC2` is NOT intended for parallel (simultaneous) execution of PROC1 and PROC2, but to connect the output of PROC1 to the input of PROC2. If this is what you want, the following method allows you to execute this way any number of commands:

```
@echo off
"H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1" > output.txt
:loop
shift
if "%1" == "" goto end
ren output.txt input.txt
"H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1" < input.txt > output.txt
goto loop
:end
type output.txt
del output.txt
```

If you want to execute all the commands in parallel, then you must use START as suggested above:

```
@echo off
:loop
start "Command %1" "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1" 
shift
if not "%1" == "" goto loop
```

Comment: Even if the pipe is NOT intended for simultaneous execution, it works and starts new instances of cmd in the same window

Answer (score 0):

You could start the multiple instances simultaneously also with `start.exe`.

```
@echo off
set i=1
:loop
if %i% GEQ 11 goto :end
start "Titel%i%" "H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe" "C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\%1"
SHIFT
set /a i+=1
goto :loop
:end
```

Or you save the variables first into p1, p2, ..., p10

```
@echo off
set prog="H[vzmwwdminta1sd]S[#]P[8080].exe"
set "param=C:\NDM_To_BatchDispatcher\NDM\INBOUND_FILES\"
set i=1
:loop
if %i% GEQ 11 goto :end
set "p%i%=%1"
SHIFT
set /a i+=1
goto :loop
:end

%prog% "%param%p1%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p2%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p3%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p4%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p5%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p6%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p7%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p8%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p9%" ^
 | %prog% "%param%p10%"
```